# Raspberry Pi Python Program First Line Error/Python Library Error

Tags: python, python-2.7, raspberry-pi

The first two lines of the program are:

```
from i2clibraries import i2c_lcd
from ABElectronics_ADCPi import ADCPi
```

No matter what line is first the Pi returns an error when I attempt to run it under Python or Python 3. All the libraries are possessed and registered. Using the shell commands the checks saying the exports worked correctly all show up correctly. However, whatever line is line 1 will return a missing module error and the i2clibraries will always return a missing module error. By keeping that as the first line I get the least errors in running, but the program still returns this:

```
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ sudo python file.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "file.py", line 1, in <module>
from i2clibraries import i2c_lcd
File "/home/pi/i2clibraries/i2c_lcd.py", line 1, in <module>
from i2clibraries import i2c
File "/home/pi/i2clibraries/i2c.py", line 1, in <module>
from quick2wire.i2c import I2CMaster, writing_bytes, reading
ImportError: No module named quick2wire.i2c
```

Given the error, what possible solutions are there to stop the first line from being unable to find its module?

Comment: Install your modules correctly.

Answer (score 0):

#### Problem

The error message is telling you that when you try to import the `i2clibraries` module, the imports that it requires (dependencies) cannot be found when it is itself is being imported.  This is specifically in the first line of `i2c.py` file - where the line

```
from quick2wire.i2c import I2CMaster, writing_bytes, reading
```

is failing.

The problem is almost certainly that your modules are not on the [Python module search path](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path).  Further info on this is given at the end of this answer should you need it.

#### Solution

There are a number of ways to resolve this.  The one [recommended by the developers of the module](https://github.com/quick2wire/quick2wire-python-api#installation) is

> To use the library without installation, add the full path of the
>   source tree to the PYTHONPATH environment variable. For example:
>
> ```
> export QUICK2WIRE_API_HOME=[the directory cloned from Git or unpacked from the source archive]
> export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:$QUICK2WIRE_API_HOME
> ```

So, you need to know where your `quick2wire` libraries are installed - from your error message, I would hazard a guess that they are in `/home/pi/i2clibraries/`, so `$QUICK2WIRE_API_HOME=/home/pi/i2clibraries/` should be your first line of the above pair.

#### Further info

You can read more generally about how to install modules on Python 2.x [on the Python website](https://docs.python.org/2/install/). You can look at what paths make up the module search path by going to an interactive Python prompt (i.e. typing `python`) and then doing.

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path
```

This will output a list containing strings representing all the paths that will be searched for modules.